# image upload + thumbnail generator

Tags: php, image

So i have my php file which recieves a file, and saves it. Works fine. However, i would like it to generate a thumbnail as well (using http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/08/cropping-an-image-to-make-square-thumbnails-in-php/)

Here is my current code:

```
<?php

$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/uploads/';

$result = 0;

$target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  $result = 1;
  square_crop($target_path, 'thumb.jpg');
}

?>
```

When i try to use the `square_crop($target_path, 'thumb.jpg');` i get a parse error on the line `if( $image[0] &gt; $image[1] ) {`

Am i using it the wrong way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&gt;` is an HTML entity for `>` - I had the same problem when I copied the code from the site - just replace all instances of `&gt;` with `>` and you're good to go!

Comment: so obvious, i probably need some sleep. thanks though :)

Comment: took me a while to figure it out at first :)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be`>` instead of `&gt;`?